# How to add custom message to order status email?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working in Bigcomerce. 
is it possible to add wording to the "order Status" email that is sent to customers when the order status is changed? See attachment. If we add wording will it appear on all emails regarding order status? If possible I would only like it to appear on the "Awaiting Shipment" order status email.

I would like to add "Your order is in progress and we will email a tracking number when your item/s are ready to be ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways that I know of to modify the email templates

1st - connect to WebDav and browse to the EMAILS folder (ROOT Level)

2nd - connect to the ADMIN panel, Settings > Design >> More >>> Emails

3rd - connect to the ADMIN panel, Settings > Design >> More >>> Template Files >>>> EMAILS

Pick the template you want to modify in your case it would be Emails/order_status_email.html

Make the changes you want and save the file. I would recommending testing it before you start blasting your customers with email alerts. It looks like the CSS is applied within the template.

When looking at the code in the order_status_email.html it shows

`<p>%%GLOBAL_OrderNumberStatusChangedTo%%</p>`

The Global Variable is used only within that template. I am not sure of a way to make this work since you don't have access to specify what template to use\send (you can't create a new one to use just for Awaiting Shipment) and they don't offer a way to break them down like that. I would recommend turning off that specific notification and using a shipping software like Shipworks etc...  This will allow you complete control over what is sent to your customers.

Comment: If we add wording will it appear on all emails regarding order status. I would only like it to appear on the "Awaiting Shipment" order status email.